# React and NodeJS: How can i use received data from Server on Client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mailchimp-api-v3.0, next.js

I want to use received data from server on client . I use a NodeJS Server with NextJS and React.

I use this function on the server:

```js
function addEmailToMailChimp(email, callback) {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://XXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXX/members',
        headers:
        {
            'Postman-Token': 'XXX',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            Authorization: 'Basic XXX',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: { email_address: email, status: 'subscribed' },
        json: true
    };
    request(options, callback);
}
```

The function will be run from this point:

```js
server.post('/', (req, res) => {
            addEmailToMailChimp(req.body.email, (error, response, body) => {
                // This is the callback function which is passed to `addEmailToMailChimp`
                try {
                    var respObj = {}; //Initial response object
                    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                      respObj = { success: `Subscribed using ${req.body.email}!`, message: JSON.parse(response.body) };
                    } else {
                      respObj = { error: `Error trying to subscribe ${req.body.email}. Please try again.`, message: JSON.parse(response.body) };
                    }
                    res.send(respObj);
                  } catch (err) {
                    var respErrorObj = { error: 'There was an error with your request', message: err.message };
                    res.send(respErrorObj);
                  }
            });
        })
```

The try method is used to verify that an email address could be successfully saved to MailChimp. An appropriate message is sent to the client.

On the Client-Side, i use this function to receive and display the data from the server:

```js
handleSubmit() {
        const email = this.state.email;
        this.setState({email: ""});
        fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email:email}),
          }).then(res => {
            if(res.data.success) {
              //If the response from MailChimp is good...
              toaster.success('Subscribed!', res.data.success);
              this.setState({ email: '' });
            } else {
              //Handle the bad MailChimp response...
              toaster.warning('Unable to subscribe!', res.data.error);
            }
          }).catch(error => {
            //This catch block returns an error if Node API returns an error
            toaster.danger('Error. Please try again later.', error.message);
          });
      }
```

The problem: The email address is saved successfully at MailChimp, but the message is always displayed: `'Error. Please try again later.'`from the `.catch` area. When i log the error from the catch area i get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

Where is my mistake? I have little experience in Node.js environments. I would be very grateful if you could show me concrete solutions. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

With `fetch` theres no data property on the response. You have to call `res.json()` and return that promise. From there the response body will be read and deserialized.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i try `fetch.json()` but this is not a function, or what do you mean? Please can you show me, what i need to change

Comment: its `res.json()`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still get the error message from the catch-area, why?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSubmit() {
        const email = this.state.email;
        this.setState({email: ""});
        fetch('/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email:email}),
          })
         .then(res => {
            console.log(res); //to make sure the expected object is returned
            if(res.data.success) {
              //If the response from MailChimp is good...
              toaster.success('Subscribed!', res.data.success);
              this.setState({ email: '' });
            } else {
              //Handle the bad MailChimp response...
              toaster.warning('Unable to subscribe!', res.data.error);
            }
          }).catch(error => {
            //This catch block returns an error if Node API returns an error
            toaster.danger('Error. Please try again later.', error.message);
          });
      }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still get the error message from the catch-area, why?

Comment: do you get the console log of the response you were expecting? Try also commenting out the toaster.success to see if that could be the issue

Comment: yes i get the console log. It shows me this: `error: "There was an error with your request"` and `message: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"` What does that mean? But the email address is stored in MailChimp...

Comment: Then there is no need for the res.json(). I have removed it above. The error looks to be coming from your try/ catch in the backend. Why dont you console log the response and the body to see what comes back form Mailchimp and see where it might be throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to change:

1. Call and wait for res.json() to get the response body as json object.
2. The result of 1. is your 'data' object that you can use directly

---

```
handleSubmit() {
    //...
    fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email:email}),
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if(data.success) {
          //...
          toaster.success('Subscribed!', data.success);
        } else {
          toaster.warning('Unable to subscribe!', data.error);
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        //...
      });
  }
```